# SDP for FFMPEG (IP addresses)

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp, sdp

I'm receiving audio via RTP, so I'm opening input from the SDP I generate. 
Media is coming from `Port_sender`, `IP_sender`. IP and port of the server for listening: `IP_server`, `Port_server`. Here is my SDP template. What of `{Port_sender, IP_sender, IP_server, Port_server}` should I put in `{%1%, %2%, %3%}` for the SDP that I feed to ffmpeg and for the SDP that I give back to the sender?

```
\n\nv=0\n
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 %1%\n
s=name\n
c=IN IP4 %2%\n
t=0 0\n
a=tool:libavformat 57.3.100\n
m=audio %3% RTP/AVP 97\n
b=AS:705\n
a=rtpmap:97 PCMU/44100/2\n"
```

Debugging it from different IPs is hard for me now. But from one computer it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to read the [RFC 4566](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566#section-4.1), it explains everything you are wondering.

- **o=** stands for *Origin*
- **c=** stands for *Connection data*
- **m=** stands for *Media descriptions*

For the question at hand, I assume you receive a `SIP INVITE` with a `SDP` offer, and you have to reply with a `SIP 200 OK` containing the `SDP` reply.

In that scenario you should reply with:

- %1% -> ***IP_server***
- %2% -> ***IP_server***, assuming a uni-cast session *"the connection address contains the uni-cast IP address of the expected data source"*
- %3% -> ***Port_sender***, since **m=** is the transport port to which the media stream is sent (Port that was defined by the sender in his offer).

Comment: Yes, this i understand, but the main question was what should i feed to ffmpeg. Because it gets SDP as URL of file(and localy its works perfectly). But i cant understand if it needs port on server to listen to the stream (and vice versa with client)